# change alignment of last row of multiple div inside container

Tags: html, css

I have a container div that contains many divs inside it as indicated in the below.

```css
.result-container {
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.result-container .item {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.result-container .item img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="result-container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://devimg.com/150x150" width="150" height="150">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://devimg.com/150x150" width="150" height="150">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://devimg.com/150x150" width="150" height="150">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://devimg.com/150x150" width="150" height="150">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://devimg.com/150x150" width="150" height="150">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://devimg.com/150x150" width="150" height="150">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://devimg.com/150x150" width="150" height="150">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://devimg.com/150x150" width="150" height="150">

  </div>



</div>
```

the parent div has text-align: center to make the child divs centered inside the parent. but i'm not satisfied with the look of the last row

[image]

is there is any way by which i can make the result as the below image

[image]

and if i used display: table is it considered good practice
appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your single DIVs actually have a fixed width (`max-width` *and*  `min-width` are set to 200px), you can use a fixed width on the container,  distribute the difference between the three DIV widths and the container width to the margins and apply `text-align: left;` to it:

```
.result-container {
  width: 614px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  text-align: left;
  etc..
}
```

```css
.result-container {
  width: 614px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

.result-container .item {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.result-container .item img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="result-container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://devimg.com/150x150" width="150" height="150">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://devimg.com/150x150" width="150" height="150">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://devimg.com/150x150" width="150" height="150">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://devimg.com/150x150" width="150" height="150">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://devimg.com/150x150" width="150" height="150">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://devimg.com/150x150" width="150" height="150">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://devimg.com/150x150" width="150" height="150">

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://devimg.com/150x150" width="150" height="150">

  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: Aha , I see you changed the width of the container to be exactly as the width of the three child divs and applied padding to the container . It solved the problem.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is use text-align-last for inline-block

```
 div.wrapper {
        width: 680px;
        text-align: justify;
        text-align-last: center;
        border: 2px solid blue;
    }

    div.item{
        width: 100px;
        border:1px solid red;
        display: inline-block;
        height:100px;
    }


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```